# How to calculate Stamp duty of North Territory in Australia?

Tags: calculation, australia

Northern Territory
Stamp Duty - General Rate Duty is calculated on the purchase price or unencumbered value of the dutiable property, whichever is the greater, as follows:

Where the dutiable value does not exceed $525,000 in accordance with the follow formula:

> D = (0.06571441 x V^2 ) + 15 * V

Where D = the duty payable in $ 
and V = the dutiable value / 1000

- From 1 July 2017, where the dutiable value exceeds $525,000, but is
  less than $3 million - 4.95 per cent of that amount.
- From 1 July
  2017, where the dutiable value is $3 million or more - 5.75 per cent
  of that amount.
- From 1 July 2017, where the dutiable value is $5
  million or more - 5.95 per cent of that amount.

I want to know if I have $500,001 amount then stamp duty is $821 but how can I calculated stamp duty to get $821?

I have take some reference from below site:
 http://www.homeloans.com.au/calculators/stamp-duty-calculator/

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: My expected result is $821. But how can I get this.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is actually as follows:

> (0.06571441 * V^2) + 15 * V, where V is the value divided by 1,000

which gives us AU$ 23,929

You find the same value using the calculator you linked to if you select "Investment" instead of "Primary Residence" or uncheck "I am a first home buyer"

**Edit:**

I don't know how they determine the $AU 821, it might be worth calling them. From looking up the [First Home Owner Discount](http://www.treasury.nt.gov.au/TaxesRoyaltiesAndGrants/HomeOwnerIncentives/FirstHomeOwnerDiscount/Pages/default.aspx), it looks like no stamp duty may be due if you qualify for the discount:

> From 1 September 2016, the Northern Territory Government introduced increased stamp duty assistance for first home buyers who purchase an established home in the Northern Territory up to the value of $650 000.
>
> The First Home Owner Discount (FHOD) is a full stamp duty concession on the initial $500 000 value of the home, which equates to stamp duty savings of up to $23 928.60.
>
> For established homes valued at more than $650 000, a stamp duty saving of $10 000 is available until 31 December 2016.
>
> source: [Department of Treasury and Finance](http://www.treasury.nt.gov.au/TaxesRoyaltiesAndGrants/HomeOwnerIncentives/FirstHomeOwnerDiscount/Pages/default.aspx)